# why 'npm run watch' not working correctly?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I have weird problem :

I am working on Laravel/Vue project and when I run `npm run watch` it run correctly and it do compile stuff when i save. the problem is after ~3min when i save it do run as it did compile stuff but nothing changed on the browser.

The solution found is that i have to run `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` every time.
does anybody have a solution for that ?
hope you can help.

Comment: Asking the obvious here but, you did refresh the page of your browser? `npm run watch` is different from `npm run hot`, the latter updates live, the former does not.

Comment: @StanSmulders yes i do refresh the page every time i save.

Comment: are you using .version()  in mix?  and the mix helper to load assets?  (sometimes I will cache in the browser and you have to hard refresh). artisan serve or local dev server?

Comment: This could be due to the cache of your browser. Look if you have disabled caching in the `development options` -> `network analysis` .